# How to use the print command from a filter function in python?

Tags: python, filter, printing

I have an assignment to write some code in python to filter palindromes. It should look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZonW.png)

This is the code I have currently but I am not able to have it print out the filtered and reversed user input:

```
palindrome=(input("Enter a sentence: "))
print("You typed in: ", palindrome)

def myFunc(s):
    r = ""
    for i in range(len(s)):
        c = s[i]
        if (c >= 'a' and c <= 'z') or (c >= 'A' and c <= 'Z'):
            r += c.upper()
    return r

filtered = filter(myFunc, palindrome)
filtered2 = (filtered)

def isPalindrome(s):         #This string reverse code was take from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-check-string-palindrome-not/
    return s == s[::-1]
s = palindrome
ans = isPalindrome(s)
if ans:
    print("Filtered:", filtered2)
    print("Reversed:", )
    print("It is a palindrome")
else:
    print("Filtered:", filtered2)
    print("Reversed:", )
    print("It is NOT a palindrome")
```

This is how is displays:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sp1X7.png)

What am I missing/doing wrong? I appreciate any help that can be provided.

Comment: `myFunc()` should return `True` or `False`. Perhaps you are looking for `map()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not use `filter` in this case. You can use `myFunc` directly for your input.

```py
palindrome=(input("Enter a sentence: "))
print("You typed in: ", palindrome)

def myFunc(s):
    r = ""
    for i in range(len(s)):
        c = s[i]
        if (c >= 'a' and c <= 'z') or (c >= 'A' and c <= 'Z'):
            r += c.upper()
    return r

filtered = myFunc(palindrome)

def isPalindrome(s):        
    return s == s[::-1]

ans = isPalindrome(filtered)
if ans:
    print("Filtered:", filtered)
    print("Reversed:", filtered[::-1])
    print("It is a palindrome")
else:
    print("Filtered:", filtered)
    print("Reversed:", filtered[::-1])
    print("It is NOT a palindrome")
```

Also if you want to print the result of `filter(myFunc, palindrome)` you have to first convert it into a `list` or `tuple` to see what's inside of it.

```py
In [11]: x = filter(lambda x:x%3, [1,2,3,4,5,6])                                                                                                                                

In [12]: print(x)                                                                                                                                                               
<filter object at 0x7f9c4014d580>

In [13]: print(list(x))                                                                                                                                                         
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```